How to increase Picker selection width?
How can I adjust the width of the list displayed when the user taps a picker? Note that I don't need to adjust width of the picker itself - only what is displayed over it.
For example, consider a picker that shows available iPad speech voices:
Picker("Voice", selection: $model.voice) {
    ForEach(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices(), id: \.identifier) { voice in
        Text("\(Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: voice.language) ?? voice.language) – \(voice.name)").tag(voice)
    }
}

If you tap the picker, you see a list that contains the following:

Even though the iPad has lots of screen width available, the list presented is so narrow that many of the choices wrap to two lines. How can I adjust the with on this width?

I'm pretty sure you cannot do change the width of menus like this. Their widths are automatically determined by the system. You can use another picker style, or make your own picker.

The code sample should not wrap. Any wrapping should be caused by something else in your code, possibly the parent view has a fixed width like the code shown below.
  VStack{
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices(), id: \.identifier) { voice in
               
                    Text("\(Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: voice.language) ?? voice.language) – \(voice.name)").tag(voice)
                       
                        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.top)
                
            }
        }
    }.frame(width: 200)


i wrote the same code below without the fixed width.
  VStack{
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices(), id: \.identifier) { voice in

                    Text("\(Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: voice.language) ?? voice.language) – \(voice.name)").tag(voice)

                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.top)

            }
        }
    }



Screen shot from Ipad pro 11 inches, 4th generation

Sorry. When I pasted the code sample above, I forgot to include the line showing that the ForEach and Text are in a Picker. They do properly expand to the full width in a VStack. The problem is that the Picker is limiting the width of the list when it is presented. I updated the code sample to show the Picker.

Okay, You can trying using a picker style: .pickerStyle(.inline) or .pickerStyle(.wheel) to get full width if it works for your usecase.

Those styles to provide more width, but they display several of the possible selections before the user taps the picker, which requires many times more vertical space. I’d like to know how to increase the width of the list with the picker in its default style.
